# How to extract all string elements from a list with tuples

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```py
mylist = [('captain', 'nemo', {'count': 698}),
          ('ned', 'land', {'count': 374}),
          ('captain', 'said', {'count': 170}),
          ('captain', 'nautilus', {'count': 142}),
          ('conseil', 'said', {'count': 142}),
          ('conseil', 'ned', {'count': 130}),
          ('said', 'ned', {'count': 126}),
          ('one', 'captain', {'count': 112}),
          ('said', 'sir', {'count': 104}),
          ('captain', 'replied', {'count': 86}),
          ('abraham', 'lincoln', {'count': 84}),
          ('nemo', 'nautilus', {'count': 84}),
          ('sea', 'nautilus', {'count': 80}),
          ('said', 'nemo', {'count': 78}), ('captain', 'sir', {'count': 72}),
          ('conseil', 'land', {'count': 72}), ('one', 'nemo', {'count': 68}),
          ('captain', 'ned', {'count': 68}),
          ('captain', 'nemos', {'count': 68}),
          ('water', 'nautilus', {'count': 68})]
```

and I want a simple set of all the string elements from this list. How do i do this?

Comment: Depending on what you can assume about `mylist`, you don't need any `isinstance` checks.

Comment: Does every tuple have type `Tuple[str,str,dict]`?

Comment: @chepner Yess, every tuple have type Tuple[str,str,dict]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a comprehension:

```
s = set(v for t in mylist for v in t if isinstance(v, str))
print(s)

# Output
{'land', 'abraham', 'water', 'sea', 'nautilus', 'captain', 'one', 'ned',
 'sir', 'lincoln', 'said', 'nemos', 'nemo', 'replied', 'conseil'}
```

As suggested by @chepner, every tuple have type `Tuple[str,str,dict]`, you can do:

```
s = set(v for t in mylist for v in t[:2])
```

**Update** suggested by @StephenRauch:

> As a note, `set(iterable)` will produce the same result as `set([iterable])`, but avoids building a list.

Comment: Per the user, you can drop the `isinstance` checks and just use `... for v in t[:2]` instead.

Comment: @chepner. I updated my answer according your comment.

Comment: As a note, `set(iterable)` will produce the same result as `set([iterable])`, but avoids building a list.

Comment: Thanks @StephenRauch. I updated my answer and give you credits for the suggestion.